# Facing issue while uploading a file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnfiN.png)I'm trying to upload an image file to firebase storage with postman using NodeJS. The file is printing as undefined, please find below the code

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Multer = require('multer');
const fileupload = require('./fileupload.js');
const upload = Multer({ storage: Multer.memoryStorage(), limits: { fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 } });

router.post("/", upload.single('file'), fileupload.upload);

module.exports = router;
```

fileupload.js

```
exports.upload = (req, res) => {
    let file = req.file;
    console.log(file);
    if (!file) {
        res.send('file not found');
        return;
    }
    res.send('file found');
}
```

Comment: I am seeing it works as expected with your code, can you provide  more information such as OS, browser, node, express versions? Also , have you tried uploading with a simple text file?

Comment: Multer is not working with google cloud functions. I've used busboys, now issue got resolved.